# Can't get POST body from request using Express.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, sails.js

I'm working on an API with NodeJS and Express (and more stuff like mongo, sockets, etc) but i'm stuck on a very simple step I believe. I'm just trying to get the information from the POST `req` object, but I get an error when trying to access `req.body`

Here's what I have:

```
var express     = require('express'),
    http        = require('http'),
    path        = require('path'),
    fs          = require('fs'),
    io          = require('socket.io');
    dynroute    = require('dynroute');

var app = express();
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3999);
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.bodyParser());

app.post('/user', function(req, res) {

    console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body));
    res.send(req.body.self);
});

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function ()
{
    console.log('App Server is now running at:' + app.get('port'));     
});
```

On the `console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body));` I get `undefined` and on the `res.send(req.body.self);` I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'self' of undefined`

I've been seaching for this type of error and usually the issue is that people do not include `app.use(express.bodyParser());` middleware , so I also tried using `app.use(express.urlencoded());` and `app.use(express.json());`, which didn't work either.

If I do a `console.log(req)` I can see the entire object but I do not get to see `body` or any of the content I'm passing when doing the POST request from a client (I'm passing it as JSON).

**I know I could use `restify` or `sails.js` to build APIs within Node but i want to do everything myself so I can learn from the experience.*

Thanks

EDIT:
I had to put the `bodyparser` middleware before the `app.router` middleware, that fixed it!

Comment: I would suggest posting information about how you're making the post request. If 'body' isn't being picked up by the req object then my first thought would be that the post request hasn't been successful.

Comment: I'm using a Chrome App called Advanced Rest Client , i'm just doing a POST request to my URL passing `['user':'kevinblanco']` as the content with application/json as the content type header.

Comment: I wish there was a single version number of express, node, whatever indicated in this question (and its answers). I reckon it is now obsolete, because a problem like this hit me today, but only when the remote server returns status code 4xx. Express 4.13.1. BodyParser 1.13.2. And the accepted answer won't help.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Move the `bodyParser` middleware above the `router` middleware!

```
var app = express();
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3999);
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(app.router);
```

Comment: Glad to help you @kevinblanco - if this solves yor problem please accept the answer :))

Comment: If you want to avoid the annoying (but temporary) deprecation warning when you use bodyParser as of today, you can do this instead `app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.json());` which does the same thing.

Comment: A great thankz to renatoargh...i'm just went mad before i get into ur answer

Comment: And don't forget to call your server with `Content-Type: application/json` in the header or there will be no data at all in `req.body`.

Comment: I ran into this solution two minutes before quit for today. Thanks!

Comment: Finding **express.bodyParser()** was hard!

Answer (score 18):

`Content-Type = "application/json"` should be one of the `Request Headers`

Comment: I don't know why you had a downvote..

Express 4.0 comes with all of the fixes listed above your comment so they were useless. While using a REST testing extension you MUST assign a Content-Type.

Awesome stuff :)

Comment: This turned out to be the case for me as well as using native fetch API in Google Chrome doesn't default content-type header to application/json so no body parsing ever occurred server side as incoming request must have been interpreted as text.

Answer (score 5):

BodyParser is no longer bundled with Express

```
npm install body-parser
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

Comment: for parsing json bodies, add the following line: `app.use(bodyParser.json())`

Comment: As of jan '16 bug is still somewhere there. I am using Express 4.13.1. BodyParser 1.13.2. Only when status code is 4xx I cannot get the body: rendering of the error page fails and node server explodes. When status code is 2xx, no problem. Tried all solutions proposed in this page. That's weird!

Comment: I am using this with express 4.16.4 version
this is not working for me


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))

app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.post('/user_create',(req,res)=>{

    console.log("trying to create a user");

    const firstName = req.body.create_first_name
    const lastName = req.body.create_last_name

    console.log("first name is "+firstName+" "+lastName);

    res.end()

})

Answer (score 1):

For me @kevinblanco's note of "I had to put the bodyparser middleware before the app.router middleware, that fix it!" did it for me. Putting it in a separate answer since its buried at the bottom.

Your code will need to look something like this:

```
app.use(favicon());
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// My routing here
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of the above-listed answers are right but at present [28-July-2020] the most suitable one is to use inbuilt's of express i.e:

```
app.use(express.json());
```

This will act as a **middleware** to accept the incoming JSON object in your request's

Answer (score 1):

in my case I have to add these two line to read post request body

```
app.use(express.json());

// add this middleware to read post request body
app.use(express.text());
```

Answer (score 0):

In Golang, you can set Content-Type as application/json before doing POST http client request to nodejs express router:

```
//Golang
import (    
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "errors"    
    "net/http"      
)

//method := "POST"
//url := "http://ip:port/api/router"

func request(method string, url string, data interface{}, pHeader map[string]string) {
    pBody, err := json.Marshal(data)
    if err != nil {
        return []byte{}, err
    }
    request, err = http.NewRequest(method, url, bytes.NewBuffer(pBody))
    if(err!=nil ){
        return []byte{}, err
    }
    request.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

    //add header params if any
    for key, head := range pHeader {
        request.Header.Add(key, head)
    }

    client := &http.Client{}
    resp, err := client.Do(request)
    if err != nil {
       return []byte{}, err
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close() 
}

//NODEJS

//app.js
var express = require('express');
...

var app = express();
app.use(express.json());


var router= require('path/to/router.js');
//use the router
app.use('/api', router);
...

//router.js    
router.post('/router', function (req, res, next) {
    //log request body to view its values of incoming request
    console.log('req.body', req.body)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Express has an inbuilt method for recognizing JSON objects from POST requests coming from the client end. Instead of using body-parser you can use this in your index.js file:

> app.use(express.json());

Answer (score 0):

You must install `bodyParser` and then use it on your app like this:

```
// middlewares
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(sucursalRoutes);
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
```

Hope this have helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `bodyParser`. Simply add the following lines -

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
```